# Calculating force on the side wall of a container

Tags: definite-integrals, physics

My daughter is busy with Calculus AB and she asked me about a problem that she was having. In one of her multiple choice quizzes, the examiner asked about the force on the side of a half full cylinder that is lying on it's side. The cylinder is 20 feet long and has a diameter of 12 feet. The fluid has a density of 50.

The cylinder would look something like this:

[image]

My daughter got the right answer but only when she ignored the length of the cylinder. That seems wrong to me. If a dam is 1 foot wide then the force of the water on the dam wall would be a lot less than it would be for a dam that was 10000 feet wide.

It's been a while but looking up the formula in her notes says that it should be this:

$$
\int_a^b \rho \cdot h(y) \cdot L(y) dy
$$

The formula for the circle is:

$$
x^2+(y-6)^2=6^2
$$

In terms of x that would be:

$$
x=\sqrt{6^{2}-\left(y-6\right)^{2}}
$$

h(y) is the depth of the slice. The L(y) dy is the area of each slice. In this case, the slice is 20 long and has a width of 2 times x (the formula above).

which is:

$$
\int_0^6 \biggl( 50 \cdot (6-y) \cdot 20 \cdot 2 \cdot \sqrt{6^{2}-\left(y-6\right)^{2}}\biggl) dy
$$

Is that correct or is the length of the cylinder supposed to be ignored? Is the area a 2d slice that only includes the side wall itself or is the area a slice that includes a full horizontal slice of the container?

Comment: To add to that, the only way that to get to that answer is to ignore the 17 which is the length of the container.

Comment: I deleted the comments including the actual question and answer to keep this question generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area under pressure in question does not depend on the length of the cylinder. Think about a diver, the pressure only depends on the depth of submersion. It does not matter whether the diver is in a tank of water or in the ocean. The length would be important if we needed to find force acting on the side of the tank.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense in the context of the question. Why would area be important if only depth was relevant? The question is also asking for the force on the side, not the pressure.

Comment: @Graymatter: $Force=pressure \cdot area$. The nature of pressure in liquid is that it is considered equal in all directions. Basically, oil is pulled by gravity but the tank stops it from going down. The molecules of oil want to escape the tank. The area is important because more molecules hit bigger area. Pressure depends on depth that's why we need to integrate pressure times area by depth (different area and different pressure at different depth).

Comment: There is a difference between a diver who is under the water and the force exerted on the side of the container. A diver in the container will experience a consistence pressure based on depth. The force of all of the liquid isn't exerted on the diver but it it exerted on the side wall. As you said, $Force = pressure \cdot area$. That's what the question is about. Is the area referred to in the question the area of a full horizontal slice of the tank?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the last part of your updated answer. The length is important when finding the force on the side of the tank so the answers in the quiz question were incorrect. That's exactly what the question was asking for but they ignored the length in their answers.